# Is there a way to make angular dialog box resize-able?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular-material

I've searched for the solution everywhere, but had no luck with it. I was able to find many modal dialog examples which work exactly like I want my dialog box to work, please take a look on Basic example:
https://mazdik.github.io/ng-modal/. 
Source code: https://github.com/mazdik/ng-modal.
And I was trying to make regular angular material dialog box resize-able: https://stackblitz.com/angular/rknvmmmgbba?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdialog-overview-example-dialog.html
I've tried CSS resize parameter and it worked fine in Chrome but it doesn't work in Edge browser, which is why I cannot use it.
Angular solution would be the best but if there isn't any, pure JS/CSS will help. Thank you

Comment: Hey, check out the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56776046/how-to-make-angular-material-dialog-re-sizable-in-angular-7

Comment: First answer doesn't work with my example and second answer is what I've tried, but it won't work in Edge browser.

Comment: this could help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8960193/

Comment: css **resize** property is not a cross browser solution. Have a look https://www.caniuse.com/#feat=css-resize. You have to manually resize the dialog by stretching `width` and `height`. and someone did this https://stackoverflow.com/a/56787782/11719787